# d3.js interferes with form element?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to put a few text inputs on the same web page as where I have a d3.js svg element. I append the svg to a div within the html, and then have the form in the `<body>` before this div. The text input appears, but I am not able to edit it on either Firefox or Chrome. As soon as I don't include the d3.js script on the page, the form element works fine. What could be happening to cause this? I already have some standard html buttons, and they are working fine.

Here's what I've tried.

1. Renaming the text input and making sure neither its name nor its id clash with anything existing.
2. Explicitly setting the readonly property to false in javascript

What else can I try? I don't see anything all that on point in SO but apologies if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no part of the content that D3 creates overlaps your textbox. If you can get to the textbox by tab:ing, it could just be stuck behind some invisible content. Try positioning stuff differently to overcome this if it seems to be the issue.